# Can you have a different theme based on user group/perms?

Tags: cms, permissions

Just asking if you can do a different theme for the same page based on user group or permissions?
Is there a way of doing it or should I code into the php index to do the switch.

I want to give a view to the developers and one to the content team while building.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Advanced Template Manager](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedtemplatemanager) by NoNumber

With Advanced Template Manager you have the possibility to assign template styles to just about anything you want (URLs, OSx, User IDs, Browsers, Tags etc..). However it's not compatible with T3 or Gantry FW.

You may have to go for the pro version for all the features but I can highly recommend these extensions. There is also a free version that you could test?

Hope this helps.